# How to get data day by day in SQL if there are some reletionships?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 table (payment_type, sales, payments, sale_items).
Below I put photos 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are some reletionships. The table payment_type has type of payments like sponsor, card, money and they are related to table payments with name payment_type_id. I have two tables (sales and sale_items). When customer buys some products it is a new sale and products are sale_items. The table sale_items has product name, product price and count and sale_id. Sale releted to sale_items and payments like sale_id. Customer can pay with card, money or sponsor_card. The table sales has amount, sale_date. The column amount is sum of product's prices. Also I have the table payments. It has 
payment_type_id, sale_id, amount. payment_type_id and sale_id was related. amount is sum of product's prices but it is divided by payment type like when customer buy product can pay with money and card

Question: I should get by date sum of amount and sum product's count like day by day in sql. Result should be:

[image]

SQL Query (from comment):

```
select to_date(TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date, sum(p.amount) as price
from sales s join
     payment_type p
     on p.sale_id = s.id join
     t_references r
     on p.payment_type = r.id
where r.code = 'sonsor' and
      s.sale_date between '01-07-2019' and '03-07-2019
group by date order by date asc
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into `SUM` or `GROUP BY`?

Comment: there is my sql request:

Comment: select to_date(TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date, sum(p.amount) as price
from sales s
 join payment_type p on p.sale_id = s.id
 join t_references r on p.payment_type = r.id
 where r.code = 'sonsor'  and s.sale_date between '01-07-2019' and '03-07-2019
group by date order by date asc

Comment: how did you get 50 as sum_amounts and 12 as sum_counts for the date 01.07.2019. i mean, what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Please update your the question with a minimum of replacing the sample data with text instead of pictures.  See the help section [ask].

Comment: sure I will update as soon as